# JSF submitting which is not a form

Tags: jsf-2

I have a **jsf file which does not contain form**. In that jsf file i have a label and a function called `onlableclick` with no parameters. The function confirms to the user whether he wants previous attachments or not and stores it in the hidden variable in the jsf file. I need this changed value of the variable to be changed in the corresponding bean, but it is taking the default value.

How to submit this jsf file which is not a form and get the changes affected in the bean variable? let me know if you wanna see the code!

In the jsf file:

```
<rich:tab styleClass="jsf-tab-panel  basicFormFullWidth" 
    action="#{CTDConcessionBean.getAttachScreen}"
    onlabelclick="**return fnCommonRadioCheckRevise();**" >  
    <f:facet name="label">
    <h:panelGroup>
    <h:graphicImage value="${contextPath}/img/tab_optional.gif" /><br/>                  
    <h:outputLabel 
    value="&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;Attachments&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;&#160;">     
    </h:outputLabel>
    </h:panelGroup>
    </f:facet>
    <ui:include src="/pages/concession/CTDConcessionAttachments.xhtml">     
    </ui:include>
    </rich:tab>
```

In the javascript:

```
 function fnCommonRadioCheckRevise()
    {
   var flag = true;

         if (confirm("Do you want to add the attachments") == true) {
             document.getElementById("strReviseAttachFlag").value='Y';


            flag= true;
            } else {
                 document.getElementById("strReviseAttachFlag").value='N';

                flag=true;
            }


    return flag;
    }
```

Comment: Sharing your code is more likely to help other people answering the question you have.

Comment: the problem is i cant add form here.. its a 10yr old proj.. there would be problems in validations if i add a form..

Comment: Then correct the validations…

Answer (score 0):

I don't run Richfaces but I think something like this might work:

```
<h:form>
    <a4j:jsFunction
        name="settotrue"
        action="#{bean.setVar(true)}">
    </a4j:jsFunction>
    <a4j:jsFunction
        name="settofalse"
        action="#{bean.setVar(false)}">
    </a4j:jsFunction>
</h:form>
```

with

```
public void setVar(boolean var) {
 ....
}
```

Call it from the script with settotrue() or settofalse().

The form should'nt mess with validations as there is nothing in it.

As said, idea is completely untested.